# Get Current Sprint/Iteration in a Build Process Template?

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, tfs, msbuild

How can the current TFS sprint/iteration number be included in the build number for a TFS 2012 build template?

i.e. If current iteration is Release 1/Sprint 5, would like to have build number be: 1.5.(rev number).

Currently using ReleaseDefaultTemplate.11.1.xaml (Release Management for Visual Studio 2013 build process template).

Answer (score 2):

Very cool!

You would need to run something prior to the "BuildNumber" task in the workflow (that's the first activity) to go retrieve and build that data. There is no OOB help, and i would suggest that you use PowerShell to retrieve the data and set the builddetails. I say PowerShell as this will be able to be reused when you move to TFS 2015 and the new build system.

An alternative that i have used is to set the build number to "mybuild_1.5.{build}.{revission}" and use PowerShell to parse out that number. This is easy as you can use existing PowerShell to achieve it. It does however require that at the end of the sprint that you go increment the number. Not ideal, but only seconds to achieve.

https://github.com/tfsbuildextensions/CustomActivities/blob/master/Source/Scripts/ApplyVersionToAssemblies.ps1

Comment: Thanks. Have any examples of how to retrieve release/iteration in Powershell?

Comment: So... first you need a Team as current sprint is team specific. Then you need to find that teams Iteration Root, and then match the current date to an Iteration date under that root. Not sure how you will figure Team? A user can be in more than one team...